# some troubles with WPF and Windows XP

Tags: wpf

is .net framework 3 compatible with xp? i install visual studio 9.0 (.net 3.5) on win XP. when i compile a WPF project and try to run it, this error occurs:

```
cannot initialize application ...... at address 0x<some digits>
```

(antivirus protection is off)

after first fail of wpf, all other project types (windows application, console &...) after compiling don't run.
where is problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF and .NET 3.5sp1 are supported on XP.  You can create WPF applications with run on Windows XP.

It sounds like you have some other issue on your XP system.  If other project types (ie: console) are failing, this is most likely some other, more serious issue.

---

Edit:

The [System Requirements for .NET 3.5sp1, including WPF, are listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882520.aspx).  Basically, you need to have XPsp2 or better if you're using 32bit Windows XP, but both 32bit and 64bit XP are supported fully.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: which edition of windows xp you are using? I have great troubles...

Comment: @Sourush: I'm using a fully updated version, now.  I've also done this on XP sp2.  This is a fully supported configuration, however - it sounds like you have some other (serious) issues with your setup.

Comment: @Sorush: I added a link to the actual requirements page.  As long as you have XP sp2, it should work fine.  If not, there's some other system issue occurring.

Comment: I understand what happens: i was using windows XP Qoqnus publish, that changes many dlls in windows/system32 . installing 2008 sp2 version fixed the problem. thanks.